# How to get request from telegram api use tor?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, tor

my country, telegrams are blocked, so I try to access it through a **tor**, the ip changes, and the connection to the telegram api does not occur.

```
import requests

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150',
    'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'
}

url = "https://api.telegram.org/"
url_ip = "http://httpbin.org/ip"

def get_updates_json(request):  
    response = requests.get(request, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
    return response

print(get_updates_json(url_ip).text)
print(get_updates_json(url).text)
```

**Output the following error message**

> SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max               retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:     WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1051)')))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import requests

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150'
}

url = "https://api.telegram.org/"
url_ip = "http://httpbin.org/ip"

def get_updates_json(request):
    response = requests.get(request, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
    return response

print(get_updates_json(url_ip).text)
print(get_updates_json(url).text)

Comment: Please add some explanation too.

Comment: and what actually changed?

Comment: In a proxy string, socks5h:// and socks4a:// mean that the hostname is
resolved by the SOCKS server. socks5:// and socks4:// mean that the
hostname is resolved locally